# Rails migrations: self.up and self.down versus change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Looks like the new rails version has "change" versus self.up and self.down methods.

So what happens when one has to roll back a migration how does it know what actions to perform. I have the following method that I need to implement based on an online tutorial:

```
class AddImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :image_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :image_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :image_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :image_file_name, :string
    remove_column :users, :image_content_type, :string
    remove_column :users, :image_file_size, :integer
    remove_column :users, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end    
end
```

How can I do the same using the new change method?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method

Answer (score 119, accepted):

For many operations **rails can guess what is the inverse operation** (without problems). For example, in your case what is the reverse operation of `add_column` to call when you rollback? Of course it's `remove_column`. What is the inverse of `create_table`? It's `drop_table`. So in these cases rails know how to rollback and define a `down` method is superfluous (you can see in the documentation the [methods currently supported from the change method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method)).

But pay attention because *for some kind of operation you still need to define the `down` method*, for example if you change the precision of a decimal column how to guess the original precision on rollback? It's not possible, so you need to define the `down` method.

As said, I suggest you to read the [Rails Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 37):

**Better to use Up, Down, Change:**

**On Rails 3 (Reversible):** which should add new column on up and fill all records in table only on up, and only delete this column on down

```
def up
  add_column :users, :location, :string
  User.update_all(location: 'Minsk')
end

def down
  remove_column :users, :location
end
```

**But:**

You had to avoid using change method which allows to save some time. For example, if you didn’t need to update column value immediately after it’s adding you would cut this code down to like this:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :location, :string
end
```

On up it will add column to table and remove it on down. Much less code and it’s a profit.

**On Rails 4:** one more useful way to write what we need in one place:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :location, :string
  reversible do |direction|
    direction.up { User.update_all(location: 'Minsk') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice explanation bro

Comment: reverting? is also a good way to tell the direction you're going inside the change

Comment: None of this works. I just keep getting `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`.

Comment: there are situations where rails fail to rollback migration.
please view their [help](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/IrreversibleMigration.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
class AddImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :image_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :image_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :image_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.but what would happen if you were to roll back. would it know what to do?

Comment: I overslept. Aldo 'xoen' Giambelluca explain everything.