# ruby on rails: ratyrate on rails 5? migration error aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm trying to get back into RoR after a long hiatus, and was getting an error when I tried to `rails db:migrate`:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
```

the errors continue...

I'm thinking its because of the `gem ratyrate`.

In one of the migration files:

```
class CreateRatingCaches < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
      create_table :rating_caches do |t|
        t.belongs_to :cacheable, :polymorphic => true
        t.float :avg, :null => false
        t.integer :qty, :null => false
        t.string :dimension
        t.timestamps
      end

      add_index :rating_caches, [:cacheable_id, :cacheable_type]
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :rating_caches
    end

end
```

is it because rails 5 don't use `def self.up` / `def self.down`? and instead should be using `def change`?

If that's the case, is it okay for me to just change the `def setf.up` to `def change` and then remove the `def self.down` block?

In addition to this, why is there even a `def self.down` calling to drop the table when its creating the table? Does it not get executed, only when you `db:rollback` the database?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you change to `def change` and drop the `self.down` method. The `up` and `down` are only necessary when you're doing some custom stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Migration` the migration is cancelled.
You should therefore inherit from `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]` and the migration should work. Change the first line to:

```
class CreateRatingCaches < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

(5.1 specifies the rails version, adapt acordingly, e.g. `ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]` etc.)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365129/rails-migrations-self-up-and-self-down-versus-change) for more information about change vs. up/down in migrations or read [this part](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method) in the official guide for detail information about the different aspects about them.